# How do I capture the 7th line of buffered PHP output into a variable?

Tags: php, buffer

I want to get the 7th line of this buffered file to be a variable.

This is my code so far:

```
<?php
ob_start();
require 'example.php';
$output = ob_get_clean();
?>
```

Comment: Presuming they have actual new lines separating them, `$lines = explode("\n", $output); $seventhLine = $lines[6] ?? '';`

Comment: it's already there in the `$output` as string, just treat it as such. ^ just like Wesley did

Answer (score 2):

You could use `preg_split` to split each line by CR?LF, and then access the 7th line, if it exists:

```
$lines = preg_split ('/\r?\n/', $output);
$line = "";
if (sizeof($lines) >= 7) {
    $line = lines[6];
}
```

I am deliberately choosing to use `preg_split` here rather than `explode` so that we may cover line endings being both LF (Unix) and CRLF (Windows).